# When Parsing Bitmap files, how do I replace the WORD and DWORD data types?

Tags: c++, windows, linux, header, bitmap

In windows you can include the windows.h header file when trying to parse bmp files and the dataTypes WORD and DWORD are predefined for you (from what I have read). In linux, I need to use these dataTypes, but I do not know how to define them and cannot include the windows.h header. How do I go about doing this in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include `<stdint.h>`, and then you can portably replace `WORD` with `uint16_t` and `DWORD` with `uint32_t`. And `BYTE` with `uint8_t`, of course:

If you want you can add the following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
typedef uint32_t DWORD;
typedef uint16_t WORD;
typedef uint8_t BYTE;
```

But beware! If you want to be portable, you must have in mind the endianness of the multi-byte values. Microsoft code almost always assume little-endian, but Linux can be run in both little and big-endian machines.

**UPDATE**:

Your new problem you talk about in the comments about the `BITMAPFILEHEADER` is not related to the type of the fields but to the *packing* of the struct: the compiler may add padding bytes between fields in the struct in order to satisfy alignment (or other requirements).

Microsoft compilers align integer type to an address multiple of its size. That is, `WORD` and `SHORT` values are aligned to an address multiple of 2, and `DWORD` and `LONG` values to multiple of 4.

If you see the definition of your struct:

```
typedef struct {
    WORD    bfType;      //offset 0
    DWORD   bfSize;      //offset 4
    WORD    bfReserved1; //offset 8
    WORD    bfReserved2; //offset 10
    DWORD   bfOffBits;   //offset 12
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;
```

Note that the `bfSize` field is sized 4 bytes, so it will be aligned to a multiple of 4. Instead of being in offset 2 of the struct, it will be in offset 4, adding 2 padding bytes.

Now, all Windows headers all compiled with the option `#pragma pack` that tells the compiler to ignore the alignment restrictions in struct fields. So the former struct is actually:

```
#pragma pack(push)
typedef struct {
    WORD    bfType;      //offset 0
    DWORD   bfSize;      //offset 2
    WORD    bfReserved1; //offset 6
    WORD    bfReserved2; //offset 8
    DWORD   bfOffBits;   //offset 10
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;
#pragma pack(pop)
```

The GCC compiler supports the `#pragma pack` only as a compatibility with MS compilers, and only with x86 compilers.

If you want to go fully portable you should read the struct directly, but read the bytes as a stream and build the values one by one (read 2 bytes into `bfType`, read 4 bytes into `bfSize`, etc.)

If you want to go portable to other Linux you can use the GCC pragma (but beware of the endiannes):

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)) {
    WORD    bfType;      //offset 0
    DWORD   bfSize;      //offset 2
    WORD    bfReserved1; //offset 6
    WORD    bfReserved2; //offset 8
    DWORD   bfOffBits;   //offset 10
} BITMAPFILEHEADER;
```

Comment: would I do this like so?: typdef uint16_t DWORD

Comment: how large should the LONG datatype be? my guess would be 32 bits but I'm getting weird results when parsing my bitmap file,  the reservedbits1 and 2 variables of my bitmapfileheader don't just contain zeroes like they should

Comment: @kjh: Right, LONG is a 32 bit signed integer, that is a `int32_t`. Your new problem is not related with the data type but with the _packing_ of the struct... Please see the updated answer (the comment is just too short).

Comment: completely disregarded the endianness part. Thanks a ton,